# App pushs local notification of older version

Tags: ios, push-notification

In an older version of the app is code that produces a local notification, but since an update, the code is removed. Nevertheless some users that update to the new version through the App Store get those notifications. 
How is this possible?

Comment: Maybe the notification was scheduled before and are not canceled?

Comment: as a date is the current date set, so it should be fired immediately.